# How can I call callback function in async.eachSeries callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, node-request, node-async

I'm trying to call callback function after `eachSeries` is done, but IT doesn't work at all. It doesn't print `2` that's supposed to print when It's called but It prints `4` after first function is called. Is there any idea about it? Thank you!

```
async.waterfall([
      function(callback) {
        console.log("1");
        let eroJson = [];
        rp(optForReddit).then(function(redditJSON) {
          let posts = redditJSON.data.children;
          async.eachSeries(posts, function(item, callback) {
            if (isVideo(item.data.url)) {
              eroJson.push(getAlbumId(item.data.url));
            }
            callback(); // callback function after eachSeries
          }, function() {
            callback(eroJson); // call next callback
          });
        })
      },
      function(redditJSON, callback) {
        console.log("2");
        callback() // call another function
      }
)],
     function(){
         console.log("Last one");
     }
```

);

Comment: should the second function call callback?

Comment: @JaromandaX This is a part of code. I just simplified the code  that's why it doesn't seem to call call callback in second function. but second function should run `console.log` line anyways

Comment: your getAlbumId is synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: @AsifSaeed getAlbum function is this short code.  `function getAlbumId(str) {
  return str.split('/')[3];
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the callback names. it seems like you are overriding callback Names

```
    async.waterfall([
          function(waterfallCallback) {
            console.log("1");
            let eroJson = [];
            rp(optForReddit).then(function(redditJSON) {
              let posts = redditJSON.data.children;
              async.eachSeries(posts, function(item, callback) {
                if (isVideo(item.data.url)) {
                  eroJson.push(getAlbumId(item.data.url));
                }
                callback(); // callback function after eachSeries
              }, function() {
                waterfallCallback(eroJson); // call next callback
              });
            })
          },
          function(redditJSON, waterfallCallback) {
            console.log("2");
            waterfallCallback();
          }
    )], function(){
            console.log("Done executing all waterfall functions");
    });
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/cXjAZR3w here's the full code for you. after I changed named all the callback functions to waterfallCallback, It still doesn't work. `1 4` Is what I got after run the code.

Comment: function 2 and 3 in your waterfallchain not even called. and the final callback of waterfall will only invoke when all the functions call there callbacks

Comment: whare are your redditJSON and optForEroshare defined?

Comment: what do you mean? I can see they are called

Comment: redditJSON is what I got after run `request-promise(rp)`  and optForEroshare is defined in function 2

Comment: ok i got the problem. use  waterFallcallback(null, eroJson); instead of waterFallcallback(eroJson);

Comment: in your second function Ero. is not defined anywhere so its throwing errror. take care of that aswell

Comment: in the second function do waterFallcallback(null, optForEroshare); instead of waterFallcallback(optForEroshare);

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/zpjrra/async-waterfall-in-nodejs check this a better way of writing async.waterfall

Comment: oh my god you are awesome.. I wanna give you a million reputation